# List with multiple look-up columns (2) showing additional field

Tags: list

I have a list (Driving Offences) which has a column (Driver) that is a LookUp, the LookUp references a list (Drivers), the Drivers list has a LookUp to another list (Office).

When adding the LookUp column Driver to Driving Offences I cannot select Office as 'Add a column to show each of these additional fields:'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint you can not add additional column information for lookup of lookup column.
And for additional information :

**This is limitation in sharepoint. The additional fields cannot be of type Currency, Person, Lookup, Calculated, Custom Columns**

[And for reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0753df63-8b30-4594-a8bd-ef8ba9514103/content-type-or-lists-lookup-column-cant-show-additional-fields-which-are-choice-or-lookup-columns?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Ah ok - thanks, are there any workarounds? Because the driving offences list we need to create views so we can provide to department managers without seeing offices that do not belong to them.

Comment: How data is added or populated? Is it scratch development? If so you can change the structure of the list